# WIX: Saving user input in xml file

Tags: wix

I want to show a custom dialog which will have two text box.After the user types these information(and clicks next) , I want to save the data in an xml file.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. create a **deferred** custom action that creates the file and adds all the user data. This is really easy if you can use managed custom actions (DTF). Note that you will have to delete the file you created during uninstall and rollback scenarios!
2. Deploy an xml file with dummy data during the installation and use the *XmlFile* / *XmlConfig* elements to replace the dummy data with the user data using an *XPath* query. The xml file will be managed by the install process, so no worrying about uninstall and rollbacks.

For a good Wix tutorial see http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/index.php

If you need more information about either option, just let me know.

Comment: +1. I would recommend going for the second option - in this case WiX and Windows Installer will do the most of the job for you. And avoid custom actions as much as possible. It should be a last resort.

Comment: Make sure that any properties you modify are UPPERCASE.  That makes them public properties and the installer will make sure to use them correctly.